# I'm trying to pull a list of items from sharepoint online using powershell csom

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, csom

I can get the list data - but it's all of the list history and not just the most current version for the items.  I don't see a version ID field to filter off older versions of the item.  Is there a way to do this with csom and powershell?

Here is my current code - I just need a way to filter to active items.

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
   
#Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl = "XYZ"
$ListName="ABC"

#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred= Get-Credential
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
  
#Set up the context
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$Context.Credentials = $credentials
   
#Get the List
$List = $Context.web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
 
#sharepoint online get list items powershell
$ListItems = $List.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())
$Context.Load($ListItems)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()      
 
write-host "Total Number of List Items found:"$ListItems.Count

#Loop through each item
$ListItems | ForEach-Object {
    If ($_["Status"]  = "Returned") {
        #Get the Title field value
        write-host $_.ID
        write-host $_["Title"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please run the below PowerShell CSOM script as an admin:

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
   
#Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl = "https://****.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"
$ListName="ABC"

#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred= Get-Credential
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
  
#Set up the context
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$Context.Credentials = $credentials
   
#Get the List
$List = $Context.web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
 
#sharepoint online get list items powershell
$Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$Query.ViewXml = "<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID'/><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Choice'>Returned</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"

$ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query)
$Context.Load($ListItems)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
 
Write-host "Total Number of Items:"$ListItems.count
 
#Loop through each List Item
$ListItems | ForEach-Object {
     #Get the Title field value
     write-host $_.ID
     write-host $_["Title"]  
     Write-host " ************* "
}
```

[image]

[image]

========================== **Updated Answer** =========================

```
$Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$Query.ViewXml = "<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID'/><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Choice'>Returned</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
```

Query the items in the current list whose [Status] column value  is equal to "Returned"

[image]

[image]

Comment: I will give that a try - can you highlight what was changed from the original script?  Is history turned on for your example site and do the items have multiple entries in the history?  Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi Mike. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day! Note: [Status] is Choice column

Comment: EchoDU_MSFT - I appreciate you taking the time to reply with this info.  I was able to get the query working with your help.  Thanks again